# Insert Nested data classes into Room db

Tags: android

I'm in situation where i have other model classes nested inside a parent class , and the thing is that i want to insert the model classes into room db but it is asking me to use type converter but i don't know  to and from which type should i convert the data class , this is my code

```
data class FixturesMergedModels (
    @Embedded var event: Event,
    @Embedded var teamXX: TeamXX,
    @Embedded var awaylogo: testAwayLogoModel

)
```

- My Event Model

````
@Entity
data class Event(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var evenid : Int?,

    @SerializedName("dateEvent")
    var dateEvent : String?,
    @SerializedName("strTime")
    val strTime : String?,
    @SerializedName("strThumb")
    val strThumb : String?,
    @SerializedName("strHomeTeam") //
    val strHomeTeam : String?,
    @SerializedName("strAwayTeam") //
    val strAwayTeam : String?,
    @SerializedName("idAwayTeam")
    val idAwayTeam: Int?,
    @SerializedName("idEvent")
    val idEvent: Int?,
    @SerializedName("idHomeTeam")
    val idHomeTeam : Int?,
    @SerializedName("intHomeScore") //
    val intHomeScore : String?,
    @SerializedName("intAwayScore") //
    val intAwayScore  : String?

)```

* Home Team Model ( teamxx)
````

@Entity
data class TeamXX(

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var homeTeamID : Int?,
@SerializedName("strTeamBadge")
val HomestrTeamBadge: String?
```

)```

- Away Team Model

```
data class testAwayLogoModel (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var awayTeamID : Int?,
    @SerializedName("strTeamBadge")
    val AwaystrTeamBadge: String?
)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the google developer website, you should use @Embedded for your event and teamXX class. Here is a short example given at their website.

```
data class Address(
val street: String?,
val state: String?,
val city: String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "post_code") val postCode: Int)

@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val firstName: String?,
    @Embedded val address: Address?
)
```

for more detail you can visit here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in my room database abstract class what should i pass as an entity should i be the address or User class in the entities field ?

Comment: it should be User class.

Comment: it confused me little bit and i have editted the post above , i have read in the documentation also that there are different relashionship but the one you suggested might not fit my code , can yu please take a look again and see what could be wrong

Comment: you can use class FixturesMergedModels for Dao. When you make API call and once it success, you feed your data to this class along with var event: Event,
    var teamXX: TeamXX, var awaylogo: testAwayLogoModel. If you already have data and it is same you bypass inserting into the Dao. when you want to display your Dao data into views, you just pass query to your FixturesMergedModels.

Comment: Well yeah for the dao im using that parent class , but the main issue still lies with the implementation of the relashionship between all models

Comment: I am not sure what type of relationship you have in your database but here is a best example given by one of the user please checkout it.https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542 Also, you can get rid of Serializable, it will slower the process. Use parclable.